# Writing binary data to a socket (or file) with Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a socket connection, and the 3rd party listener on the other side expects to see data flowing in a very structured manner. For example, it looks for an unsigned byte that denotes a type of message being sent, followed by an unsigned integer that denotes the length of message, then another unsigned byte which is really a bit field with some flags set or unset and etc...

How would I do this in python? I'm just wondering how to reliably generate this data and make sure I'm sending it correctly (i.e. that I'm really sending an unsigned byte rather than say a signed integer or worse, a string).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module to build a buffer and write that.

Answer (score 4):

A very elegant way to handle theses transitions between Python objects and a binary representation (both directions) is using the [Construct library](http://construct.wikispaces.com/).

In their documentation you'll find many nice examples of using it. I've been using it myself for several years now for serial communications protocols and decoding binary data.

Answer (score 0):

At the lowest level, socket I/O consists of reading or writing a string of byte values to a socket.  To do this, I encode the information to be written as a string of characters containing the byte values, and write it to the socket.  I do this by creating a superstring, and then appending one character at a time.  for example, to create a Modbus/Ethernet read request:

```
    readRequest = """"""
    readRequest += chr(self.transactionID / 0x100)  # Transaction ID MSB         (0)
    readRequest += chr(self.transactionID % 0x100)  # Transaction ID LSB         (1)
    readRequest += chr(0)                           # Protocol ID MSB (Always 0) (2)
    readRequest += chr(0)                           # Protocol ID LSB (Always 0) (3)
    readRequest += chr(0)                           # Length MSB (Always 0)      (4)
    readRequest += chr(6)                           # Length LSB (Always 6)      (5)
    readRequest += chr(0)                           # Unit ID (Always 0)         (6)

    readRequest += chr(0x04)                        # Function code 4     (0)
    readRequest += chr(startOffset / 0x100)         # Starting offset MSB (1)
    readRequest += chr(startOffset % 0x100)         # Starting offset LSB (2)
    readRequest += chr(0)                           # Word count MSB      (3)
    readRequest += chr(2 * nToRead)                 # Word count LSB      (4)

    sockOutfile.write(readRequest)
```

To convert multibyte values into character strings so they can be appended onto the I/O string, use the 'Pack()' function in the struct module.  This function converts one or more single or multiple byte values into a string of individual byte values.

Of course, this method is about as simple as a hammer.  It will need to be fixed when the default character encoding in a string is Unicode instead of ASCII.

Comment: This is not a good idea. It's error prone and hard to maintain. The struct module is a much better way to do this.

Comment: Yes, I have to agree.  Unfortunately, I wrote this while learning Python, and wrote it as if I was still writing in C.